# PHP CI Controller Function Calling from outside framework

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using CI Controller and all functionality developed within the framework (Test_frame1). Now from a different domain, i like to call the identified features from my CI Framework i.e. test_frame1.

How to make such calls?
Can Test_frame1, expose any web services which can be directly called from external websites?
How the web service can be routed to private method calls within my CI Controller?
What kind of security aspects to be considered?
Any example code and explanation is highly appreciated.

Thank You,

Comment: I think you should explain what you want in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to make your reusable functions in Test_frame1 available as API calls.
Here is a good link but a long read too.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter-2/

Answer (score 0):

I had some similar issue and I've solved a little bit tricky but it working :)

I have a cms made in codeigniter which generate static files to the main site, it sounds bad but I try to illustrate in other way:

```
root - cms_folder (codeigniter system)
     - images 
     - js
     - assets
     - index.html
```

I want to handle the ajax requests with the codeigniter's controller and at the same time I want to hide the real path of the codeigniter folder. To make this I've made a redirect in the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*ajax_action/(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*ajax_action/(.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/cms_folder/ajaxcall/$1 [NC,P]
```

And the ajax request I've made look like this:

```
$.ajax({
    'url': '/ajax_action/'+action, // action is the ajaxcall controller's function
    'data' : {parameters},
    'type': 'POST',
    ../ other ajax settings ...
});
```

I know my english is really bad, but I hope I help with this someone at some time :)

Comment: I don't know but maybe if you change the redirect than this will work with different domains too. Have Fun!